# Julia - real time varying heatmap using PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia, heatmap

I'm working on a simulation in julia where I need a real time varying heatmap. I am using PyPlot and have tried to adopt this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385216/python-real-time-varying-heat-map-plotting) to julia as

```
  1 using PyPlot
  2 
  3
  4 ion()
  5 fig = figure()
  6 ax = fig[:add_subplot](111)
  7 img = ax[:imshow](rand(50,50))
  8 show()
  9
 10 # draw some data in loop
 11 for i in 1:10
 12     # wait for a second
 13     sleep(1)
 14     # replace the image contents
 15     img[:set_array](rand(50,50))
 16     # redraw the figure
 17     fig[:canvas][:draw]
 18 end
```

The code runs but the imshow is not updated, I guess this is due to the fact that it is not possible to set the array of the image object like in python. How would one do this in julia though? I can get it working by just calling imshow every iteration, this does however become slow for larger loops.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. The only thing that looks a bit suspicious is `fig[:canvas][:draw]` (you are referencing the `draw` method of `fig[:canvas]` but to call it you would need `fig[:canvas][:draw]()`). Having said that, at least for me it doesn't seem necessary to explicitly call a draw on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, it was actually the () that I needed apparently.

Answer (score 0):

On `Julia v0.5 rc3` and `PyPlot` `v"2.2.1+"`, the above mentioned code just works as is on the REPL and also by running in non-interactive mode like, `julia plot.jl`,

```
julia> using PyPlot
julia> using PyPlot
julia> ion()
julia> fig = figure()
PyObject <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x3280c5f50>
julia> ax = fig[:add_subplot](111)
PyObject <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x328242410>
julia> img = ax[:imshow](rand(50,50))
PyObject <matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x31f337710>
julia> show()
julia> # draw some data in loop
   for i in 1:10
       # wait for a second
       sleep(1)
       # replace the image contents
       img[:set_array](rand(50,50))
       # redraw the figure
       fig[:canvas][:draw]
   end
```

This results in a the plot varying over time interval of 1 second.