# Animate Array Heatmap in real time

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, heatmap

With Python3, Numpy, Matplotlib, Anaconda, Spyder: I have an array that changes over time, and I want to animate its heatmap. Now I already found a variety of methods to do so, but none of these seem to work.

I tried every one of the three methods of this guy:

https://gist.github.com/take-iwiw/43b1d8bc1dcfd2f0bf19a81486985d59

None of these worked as inteded. In Spyder none worked at all, so I tried running it via Visual Code Studio, where only the third one was actually animated, but it was within a bigger (empty) grid and did not seem right overall.

So I searched more and came across this post:

[Python real time varying heat map plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385216/python-real-time-varying-heat-map-plotting)

It was a new approach and very much exactly what I wanted. I tried it out, but on Spyder it just shows the first picture and on Visual Studio Code it shows the first two like it should and then the animation window crashes.

Here is the code from DrV from this last link, though I have a feeling that this might not be the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

# create the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
plt.show(block=False)

# draw some data in loop
for i in range(10):
    # wait for a second
    time.sleep(1)
    # replace the image contents
    im.set_array(np.random.random((10,10)))
    # redraw the figure
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

I would like to have a somewhat fluid animation of this random array. The time.sleep command is just there to simulate computation time my program needs and my array wont be completely random, and is also only filled with +1 or -1. I dont need the axes or any additional info, though it would be nice if I could print a value next to it (which is animated with it).

I feel like the problem is how I execute the program. I am very new to programming, but I did similar animations before on Scilab and Fortran, which was comparably easy, so I'm asking myself what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Mostly it helps relying on the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/animation_demo.html).

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Thank you very much!